# Generate Entity Classes using Odata service

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I want to generate custom classess of my odata service. I am planning to use Entity Framework for that.

Can somebody help me on this ?

Technology I am using: .Net Framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

See here for an intro to OData and the Entity Framework:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-crud-operations

Comment: I am looking to generate classes (with edmx) at client Side using OData service. The reason is I want simple classes rather complecated service reference class.

Comment: Or another option is to to generate custom class at client end from odata service (without edmx).